# Submitting to variable pages in html form

Tags: javascript, html, post, cookies, frames

Hullo,
I am trying to post a form to variable pages by storing them in a cookie. All seems to work fine, but for the target. When I use the following code the target of the post operation remains the current page, albeit I set the target both in the form and explicitly in the function.
What is wrong in what I did?

```
<script>
 function submit(form){
    var table=leggiCookie("source");
    form.target='_parent';
    form.action = "/combustibili/"+table+".php";
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='request' method='post' target='_parent' onsubmit="submit(this);">
</form>
```

Comment: So what do you want it to do, it's opening in the same window because of the target, if you want a new window terget _blank. You're question isn't clear as to what you want it to do ...

Comment: Nope, that window appears in a frame and it should post to the enclosing window. Alternatively it would be fine to inject the name of the destination page in the action, but I do not know how to make it in JS, and doing the thing in php would be rather an overshoot.

Comment: Then you need to put the iframe id in the target of the form.`target="#iframeId"`

Comment: That form is in the frame, the post should happen in the parent of it. If I use a static action the form works as it should, my problem is that I need to use the form to post to different pages and I need to tell it to which to post.

Comment: so you need the parent window to tell the form in the frame where to send it to, is that correct ? are they both on the same domain ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain. Two pages should use the same frame and be used as the respective targets for them.